# Use of unassigned local variable 'strCity'

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is the error its giving, my biz code is fine as well as stored procedure, without "strCity" variable everything was working fine, but the moment i added this addition, is causing me trouble

```
        txtCityName.Text = null;
        string strVal = hdnOption.Value;
        IFormatProvider provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", true);
        DateTime dtStart = new DateTime();
        DateTime? dtEnd = null;
        string strCity;

        if (strVal == "today")
        {
            HideCustomSearch();
            dtStart = DateTime.Today;
            dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
            strCity = txtCityName.Text.ToString().Trim();
        }
        if (strVal == "weekly")
        {
            HideCustomSearch();
            dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).Date;
            dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
            strCity = txtCityName.Text.ToString().Trim();
        }
        if (strVal == "byweekly")
        {
            HideCustomSearch();
            dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15).Date;
            dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
            strCity = txtCityName.Text.ToString().Trim();
        }
        if (strVal == "monthly")
        {
            HideCustomSearch();
            dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Date;
            dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
            strCity = txtCityName.Text.ToString().Trim();
        }
        if (strVal == "yearly")
        {
            HideCustomSearch();
            dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Date;
            dtEnd = DateTime.Today;
            strCity = txtCityName.Text.ToString().Trim();
        }
        if (strVal == "custom")
        {
            ShowCustomSearch();
            dtStart = DateTime.Now;
            dtEnd = DateTime.Now;
            strCity = txtCityName.Text.ToString().Trim();
            strCity = null;

            hdndtStart.Value = txtdtStart.ToString();
            hdndtEnd.Value = txtdtEnd.Text.ToString();
        }
        FillGridFilter(dtStart, dtEnd, strCity);
```

P.S. its giving me error on last line "strCity" only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better still, assign `null` to `strCity`, use `else if` instead of `if` in your conditional logic and test for `strCity` being null before your call to `FillGridFilter`.

From what I can see all the possible options for your strVal variable are mutually exclusive so there is no need to force re-evaluation of it in each test.

Answer (score 2):

Your error occures because you have not got an 'else' anywhere after the ifs. The compiler can not verify that the value 'strCity' will ever be assigned (there might be a number of different options for 'strVal ').
You therefor have to assign a default value.

Writing the code as a switch statement:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06tc147t.aspx
would probable make it more clear since you can define a 'default' case in those situations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign some default value to local variables.

This error is given in your case because compiler is thinking `string strCity;` may never get assigned value.

While declaring `string strCity;` assign some value to it.

```
string strCity="";
```

or

```
string strCity=string.Empty;
```

Try this, error will go.

Comment: Local variables don't have to have a default value assigned to them. In fact, leaving out the default value triggers this exact error on this kind of code so that you can correct the conditional logic and ensure a value is set on all code paths.

Comment: @c45207 exactly varaibles dont have default values assigned to them, while declaration we have to assign them those values

Answer (score 0):

Because you have used if staments with lot of conditions. The value will be assigned at runtime to the **strCity** variable.But after the if statement the **strCity** you have used as parameter to the function **FillGridFilter** so the compiler will not sure the if condition is exicutes or not. that's way

Error

> Use of unassigned local variable 'strCity' 
>   it's showing

so better to assign the default value to the variable **strCity**

Answer (score 0):

Better to put

```
string strCity=null;
```

or
    string strCity=String.Empty;

But make sure that FillGridFilter function handles the null or empty value.

Regards,

Nitin Joshi